# Javascript: Create new Object doesn't work if is in another files

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm building a small calendar with OOP, which is work but whenever I call my new Calendar() in another js file, it complain it Calendar isn't defined and I can't understand why is that.

Some code:
Index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="monthData.js"></script>
        <script src="month.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <table>
            <tbody id="table">
                <tr id="year"></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="prev-month"> Prev</td>
                    <td id="month"></td>
                    <td id="next-month"> Next</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="days-of-week"></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>


        <script src="currentCal.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

month.js

```
window.wca = {}
};

(function() {

wca.today = new Date();
wca.currentYear = wca.today.getFullYear();
wca.currentMonth = wca.today.getMonth();

function Calendar(year, month){
    this.year = wca.currentYear;
    this.month = wca.currentMonth;
}

wca.Calendar.prototype.createCalendar = function(){
    wca.currentDayOfWeek = wca.today.getDay();
    wca.firstDay = new Date(wca.currentYear, wca.currentMonth, 1); //first day of current month
    wca.firstDayOfWeek = daysLabel[wca.firstDay.getDay() - 1]; // first dayOfTheWeek of current month
    wca.firstDayOfWeekNumber = wca.firstDay.getDay(); 
    wca.showMonth = monthNamesArray[wca.currentMonth]; //current month string
    wca.showWeekDay = daysLabel[wca.currentDayOfWeek - 1]; //current day of the week
    wca.totDayInMonth = daysPerMonth[wca.currentMonth]; //how many days are in the current month

    //Leap years
    if (wca.currentMonth == 1) {
        if((wca.currentYear % 4 == 0 && wca.currentYear % 100 != 0) || wca.currentYear % 400 == 0){
          wca.totDayInMonth = 29;
        }
    }

    var Htmltable = document.getElementById('table');
    var year = document.getElementById('year');
    var month = document.getElementById('month');
    var daysOfWeek = document.getElementById('days-of-week'); 

    year.innerHTML = '<td>'+ wca.currentYear +'</td>';
    month.innerHTML =  '<td>'+ wca.showMonth +'</td>';
    for(i = 0; i < daysLabel.length; i++)
        daysOfWeek.innerHTML = daysOfWeek.innerHTML + '<td>'+ daysLabel[i] +'</td>';

    var html = '';
    var day = 1;
    for(i = 1; i <= 6; i++){ //6 rows
        html += '<tr id="days-row">';
        for(j = 1; j <= 7; j++){ //7 coloumns
            html += '<td>'; 
            if(day <= wca.totDayInMonth && (i > 1 || j >= wca.firstDayOfWeekNumber )){
                html += day;
                day++;
            } else {
                html += '&nbsp;';
            }
            html += '</td>';
        }
        if(day >= wca.totDayInMonth){
            break;
        }
        html += '</tr>'; 
    }  
    Htmltable.innerHTML += html + '</tr>';
}

})();
```

currentCal.js

```
window.wca = {};
(function() {
    var currentCal = new Calendar(wca.currentYear, wca.currentMonth);
    currentCal.createCalendar();
})();
```

So if I put what is in currentCal in month.js everything works, otherwise I get the undefined error.
Why is that? 
Since in my Html i'm linking before month.js and then currentCal.js I thought it should already knows what Calendar(); is.

Comment: Place break point in both files where you assign window.wca and see which one is hit first. I think script you put in <body> runs before code specified in <head> so 'createCalendar' is undefined at that time.

Comment: wrap it in a function that gets called on document ready.

Comment: They are both in an anonymous function which call them in document ready

Comment: @PrzemG from breakpoints seem that month.js is the one that is called before o.o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a scope problem. Can you try putting "var wca = {};" in month.js and just using it (without window.wca = {};) in currentCal.js?

Edit: He was calling "new Calendar" which was inside a closure in the other file so it was out of the global scope for the other file. He had to remove the closure "(function() {...})" to declare this variables on a global scope and be accesible from the other file.

Comment: Unfortunately is still undefined

Comment: remove the closure on month.js. "(function() {..."

Comment: Oh Yeah! That was it! :) So no closure on month.js and no global object in currentCal.js Thank you

Comment: Glad to help. Scope in JavaScript can be difficult.